# Intersection of prime ideals in commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

The result may be well-known, in general form; but I faced difficulty in a simple case of the result. (Instead of referring to a result, I tried myself in some arguments, but came to some problems, and I want to solve these small problems I faced.)

> **Lemma:** If $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$ are prime ideals in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, and if $P_1\cap \cdots \cap P_k:=P$ is prime, then $P=P_i$ for some $i$.

Proof: Consider the natural map $f:R\rightarrow \frac{R}{P_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{R}{P_k}$; it is a ring homomorphism, with $\ker f=P_1\cap \cdots \cap P_k=P$ (prime, by assumption).

Thus, $f$ factors through $\overline{f}:\frac{R}{P} \rightarrow \frac{R}{P_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{R}{P_k}$, and this is injective.

Since $R/P$ is integral domain, so image of $\overline{f}$ should go inside $\frac{R}{P_i}$ for some $i$ (am I right? I couldn't properly justify this!)

Suppose $Im(f)\subseteq \frac{R}{P_1}$.

This forces that $\ker f\supseteq P_2\cup \cdots P_k$.

Thus, $P=P_1\cap P_2\cap \cdots \cap P_k\supset P_2\cap \cdots \cap P_k$. From this, we see that $P_1\supseteq P_2\cap \cdots \cap P_k$.

**Question $1$.** How should I proceed next?

**Question $2$.** Can one suggest some clear statements, via the CRT approach above, for the proof of Lemma?

Comment: What makes you think that the image is contained in $R/P_i$ for some $i$? That makes no sense. Actually, if the ideals $P_i$ are pairwise coprime then $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism. Anyway, this theorem has an easy proof, you don't need to use this homomorphism $f$.

Comment: @Mark: Suppose we have a direct sum of two integral domains $R_1\oplus R_2$, which we make into a ring by pointwise addition and multiplication. If $S$ is a subring of this ring with same multiplicative identity, and if $S$ is integral domain, is it not true that $S\subset R_1\oplus 0$ or $S\subset 0\oplus R_2$? (This I thought intuitively).

Comment: No, that's not true. For example, if $R_1=R_2=R$ then you can take the diagonal $S=\{(r,r): r\in R\}$. This is a subring isomorphic to $R$, and in particular an integral domain.

Comment: What's the point to use CRT to prove such a trivial result that follows immediately from the definition of prime ideals?

Comment: @user26857: $R/P_1\cap\cdots \cap P_k$ will be integral domain and sitting inside direct sums of integral domains; it pops in mind naturally to see "what happens by CRT". (I mentioned in the first lines clearly what is my doubt; I pointed out that, I want to understand gaps in my specific way of understanding, but not any alternate  proof of the lemma. The lemma is easy consequence of a small lemma (1.11 perhaps) in Atiyah-MacDonald's book, which I verified. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it more starkly, suppose each $P_i $ contains an element $x_i$ that is not in $P$.

Notice that $\prod_i x_i\in\bigcap_i P_i=P$.

Therefore, one of the $x_i$ is in $P$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $P\neq P_1$, then you can take an element $a\in P_1$ that is not in $P$. Then

$a(P_2\cap \cdots \cap P_n)\in P$

but $P$ is prime and $a\notin P$, so that

$P_2\cap \cdots \cap P_n\subseteq P$

that means

$P_2\cap \cdots \cap P_n= P$

Now you can go on supposing that $P\neq P_2$.

Thus at the end you will have that $P$ is equal to some $P_i$